# Find out flash players connection URL

Tags: flash

I have [this page](http://allindiaradio.gov.in/Default.aspx) which has a flash player trying to connect to a rtmp URL. It's the source of a live radio.

[image]

How can I find out this URL the player is trying to connect to?

I wasn't able to get much out of web inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I did another google search and found several results. The [useful one was on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/114196/how-to-find-the-stream-behind-a-flash-player).

I looked under the hood (webpage source) and saw *.m3u8 links. I downloaded this file and it was openable in text editor. Though I couldn't play this on VLC/Quicktime/Chrome. I simply googled the m3u8 file namae and came across this page: [fmscan.org/main.php?qth=Bangalore&l=77.5833333&b=12.9833333&csave=2](http://fmscan.org/main.php?qth=Bangalore&l=77.5833333&b=12.9833333&csave=2)

The RTMP live stream url opens directly in VLC and plays well! :)